# input number then take numbers front and back

Tags: java

I am trying to make this work, but I cannot.

The input for:

```
Enter number : 12345
```

should be:

```
front numbers:123

back numbers:45
```

Another example:

```
Enter number : 485
```

the output:

```
front numbers:4

back numbers:85
```

Another example:

```
Enter number : 4370
```

the output:

```
front numbers:43

back numbers:70
```

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int enter1, nominal, hundreds;

    System.out.print("enter number : ");
    enter1 = input.nextInt();


    hundreds = enter1%1000;
    nominal = enter1%100;
    System.out.println("front numbers = " + hundreds);
    System.out.println("back numbers = " + nominal);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here and keep in mind, that formatted questions attract more people. I think, in this example, you need to define what is *front* and *back*. They change in sizes according to your examples.

Comment: im sorry im new to this kind of stuff and my english is not really good either..

Comment: im sorry i ll keep your advices and try to follow them next time and i ll try to get better with this thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there: `hundreds = enter1%1000;` should be `hundreds = enter1 / 100;`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter number: ");
int num = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("front numbers = " + num / 100);
System.out.println("back numbers = " + num % 100);
```

Comment: enter1 / 100; its working! im so dumb xD thank you sir